# Getting null values when trying to parse an XML using XPATH in VBScript

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, vbscript, xml-parsing

I am new to xPath, i am trying to parse a XML given below using XPath in VbScript and I am always getting null value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-
utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-
200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2017-03-30T07:08:12.264Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2017-03-30T07:13:12.264Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse 
xmlns="http://www.cubonline.com/CubOnline/WebServices/201207">
         <RegisterAndInviteParticipantResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cub.CubOnline.WebServices.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:UserID>322988</a:UserID>
        <a:AccessCode>7EBECBBD</a:AccessCode>
        <a:LogonUrl>https://uat.sonline.com/Online/Standalone/PLogon.aspx?skin=1379+751&amp;lang=en-GB</a:LogonUrl>
        <a:AuthenticatedURL i:nil="true" />
        <a:ReportLinksURL>https://uat.sonline.com/Online/Standalone/XViewReportLinks.aspx?key=091d1e-6cd0-45fd-8c81-61ab70107f34&amp;hash=7DDEDAF4CCDD47E5880F086C62E660F8F45B2C9E&amp;skin=234</a:ReportLinksURL>
        <a:ParticipantScheduleID>791777</a:ParticipantScheduleID>
     </RegisterAndInviteParticipantResult>
  </RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Below is my VBScript code:

```
Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.resolveExternals = False
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False


If Not xmlDoc.loadXML(registerParticipantResponse) Then
'//..........do something.
End If

'//=====================================================
'//Try Xpath'ing a few values
'//=====================================================
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", 
"xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
xmlns=http://www.cubonline.com/CubOnline/WebServices/201207' xmlns:a='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cub.CubOnline.WebServices.DataContracts' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"
Dim currNode


Set currNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//*[local-
name()='RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse']/@*[local-
name()='RegisterAndInviteParticipantResult']/@*[local-name()='AccessCode']")
accessCode = ""
If Not currNode Is Nothing Then
accessCode = currNode.text
End If
```

Note:I am getting 'accesscode' is null.
So please help me how can access the value of in accesscode through Xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` characters should be taken out of the XPath, because these are not attributes but elements:

```
"//*[local-name()='RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse']/
   *[local-name()='RegisterAndInviteParticipantResult']/
   *[local-name()='AccessCode']"
```

However, since you set namespaces for use with XPath in your code, this should be more concise and straightforward:

```
"//RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse/
   RegisterAndInviteParticipantResult/
   a:AccessCode"
```

Here is an example of when `@` can be used with the original document (assuming the `o` prefix would be bound as well explicitly in the code):

```
"/s:Envelope/s:Header/o:Security/@s:mustUnderstand"
```

In general, when XPath does not find an element or attribute with the specified name, it will not return an error, but return an empty sequence instead.

Comment: I don't know this particular XPath engine, but if it's conformant with XPath 1.0 then an unprefixed element name always refers to names in no-namespace. So there needs to be a prefix used with `RegisterAndInviteParticipantResponse` and bound to the correct namespace

Comment: Ah yes, very good point, I had forgotten that about XPath 1.0, and it may well be that VBScript still uses this older version.